# Configuring settings partial using SASS Foundation and Bower

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower, partial

I'm working on a Symfony2 project, using Bower for assets management and Foundation with SASS (and grunt on top of that).

Obviously, I shouldn't edit package files, because every update change would dissapear. Yet, foundation.scss needs a settings to configure specific module. How can i handle this? Is there way to prepend a settings partial before foundation.scss?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use next way

for example we have the following folder structure:

```
bower/
   foundation/
      normalize.scss
      foundation.scss
      foundation/
        _functions.scss
        _settings.scss
        components/
    styles/
        styles.scss
        foundation/
           _settings.scss
           _button-groups.scss
```

All componenets that you want to change you should copy in your director "styles/foundation/ ... " and you should have your own file with settings for foundation

```
styles.scss:
@import "../foundation/normalize";
@import "foundation/settings"  // the copy of default settings file

// defaults components
@import "../foundation/foundation/components/accordion";
@import "../foundation/foundation/components/alert-boxes";

// components that your change 
@import "foundation/button-groups";
```